# Change mutable reference in a loop in Rust

Tags: loops, recursion, rust, borrow-checker

I have a simple recursive data structure like this:

```
    struct X{
       i:u32,
       n:Option<Box<X>>
    }
    fn new(i:u32,x:X)->X{
       X{i,n:Some(Box::new(x))}
    }
```

now I wish to iterate it in a loop.

```
    let mut x = new(7,new(3,new(4,new(0,X{i:3,n:None}))));
    let mut i:&mut X = &mut x;
    while let Some(n) = &mut i.n{
        println!("{}",i.i);
        i = &mut n;
    }
```

Unfortunately borrow checker does not seem to be happy with this code. Is there any way to make it work, or should I use raw pointers instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out. Turns out it's not as complicated

```
    use std::borrow::BorrowMut;

    struct X{
        i:u32,
        n:Option<Box<X>>
    }
    fn n(i:u32,x:X)->X{
        X{i,n:Some(Box::new(x))}
    }
    let mut x = n(7,n(3,n(4,n(0,X{i:3,n:None}))));
    let mut i:&mut X = &mut x;
    while let Some(n) = &mut i.n{
        println!("{}",i.i);
        i = n.borrow_mut();
    }
```